# Azure Automation - Download blob from URL

Tags: powershell, azure, workflow, azure-automation

I'd like to download a blob from a URL rather than providing the blob name.

However `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` doesn't have a parameter for a URL.

I'd like to use a commandlet where I don't need to specify the blob name and container name, just the URL.

Comment: Have you checked [Save-AzureVhd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495297.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Source = "http://yoursite.com/file.xml"
$Destination = "c:\application\data\newdata.xml"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Source -OutFile $Destination
```

Comment: This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. That uh… seems kind of silly to me here, but there you go.